# Can I use the same docking station for two different laptops?

Tags: laptop, battery, charging, docking-station

I got an HP G5 Docking Station for working at home and thought I could use that to connect all my stuff and to my private laptop and charge that private laptop aswell. However, obviously the two power supplies have different wattages for example. In my naive thinking I'd imagine the docking station or laptop would recognize that and deliver the right power for the corresponding device, since it says it is compatible with a whole range of wattages.

Would what I have in mind work or will I damage my private laptop with that? The private laptop has a lower wattage requirement, therefore I'm concerned about it.

Charging specs:

- work laptop (19.5V, 7.7A)
- private laptop (19.5V, 3.34A)

Answer (score 1):

There is probably not enough information about the two laptops to answer your question definitively, but using a power supply with a higher wattage than you need is not inherently bad. The important thing is that the voltage and polarisation are correct. Using an underpowered (too low wattage) PSU is bad.

Comment: You're right, I edited the specs in.

Answer (score 0):

This will work fine.

Provided the power drawn (ie wattage) is not more then the power available, and the voltages are similar it wont be a problem as a device will only draw the power it needs.  (Even if the wattage was less it would likely still work but take longer to charge, but that depends a bit on other factors).